# Curve fitting with asymetric double sigmoidal function SciPy

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, curve-fitting

I am trying to fit data with an asymetric double sigmoidal function (called "des()") and despite many attempts I can't get a very good fitting.

Best R-squared obtained is 0.96 and fit curve is far away from ymax.
I've tried playing with initial guess p0 but it didn't help to get better fitting.

How can I get better fitting?

Any help will be very appreciated.

Thanks.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as opt

xdata = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]
ydata = [1, 33, 90, 103 , 141, 96, 85, 86, 43, 32, 17, 9, 8, 6, 11, 4, 4, 1]

def des(x,a,b,c,d,e,f) : 
    y = a + (b/(1+(np.exp(-1*((x-c+(d/2))/e)))))*(1-(1/(1+np.exp(-1*((x-c-(d/2))/f)))))
    return (y)

p0 =[10,1000,1,1,1,11]
popt, pcov = opt.curve_fit(des,xdata,ydata, p0 =p0, maxfev = 1000000)

residuals = ydata - des(xdata, *popt)
ss_res = np.sum(residuals**2)
ss_tot = np.sum((ydata-np.mean(ydata))**2)
r_squared = 1 - (ss_res / ss_tot)
print(r_squared)

y = des(xdata,*popt)
fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(6,4))
ax.plot(xdata,ydata, label='data')
ax.plot(xdata,y,label='fit')
plt.legend()
plt.title('HBD',fontdict=None, loc='center', pad=None)
plt.xlabel('HBD')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')
```

[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6LCX.png)

Comment: looks like a pretty good fit to me!  why would you say it's not very good?

Comment: Max of the fit curve is still far away the max of the data even if other parts of the data curve are pretty well fitted. I was wondering if I could get something even better in term of fitting the data max or if this is the best I could hope.Thx

Comment: assuming that label is accurate and this is a  histogram, then those values would be poisson distributed.  the fit value is ~118 which would mean the upper 95%CI value would be 140 and hence plausible under reasonable assumptions.

Comment: I fit the data to to over 140 peak and sigmoidal equations with 6 or less parameters. The fit you have is at least as good as any of those. @SamMason I agree you based on these analytical results.